# How to convert Vector Layer coordinates into Map Latitude and Longitude in Openlayers

Tags: openlayers, latitude-longitude, proj4js

I'm pretty confused. I have a point:

```
x= -12669114.702301
y= 5561132.6760608
```

That I got from drawing a square on a vector layer with the DrawFeature controller.

The numbers seem...erm...awfull large, but they seem to work, because if I later draw a square with all the same points, it's in the same position, so I figure they have to be right.

The problem is when I try to convert this point to latitude and longitude.

I'm using:

```
map.getLonLatFromPixel(pointToPixel(points[0]));
```

Where points[0] is a geometry Point, and the pointToPixel function takes any point and turns it into a pixel (since the getLonLatFromPixel needs a pixel). It does this by simply taking the point's x, and making it the pixels x, and so on.

The latitude and longitude I get is on the order of:

```
lat: -54402718463.864
lng: -18771380.353223
```

This is very clearly wrong.  I'm left really confused. I try projecting this object, using:

```
.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject());
```

But I don't really get it and am pretty sure I did it incorrectly, anyways.

My code is here: http://pastie.org/909644

I'm sort of at a loss. The coordinates seem consistent, because I can reuse them to get the same result...but they seem way larger than any of the examples I'm seeing on the openLayers website...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

According to your code, the projection you are using is EPSG:900913, which is the one that Google uses. The units for this projection are meters, and the values that you obtain for the point are perfectly correct:

```
x= -12669114.702301 (longitude)
y= 5561132.6760608 (latitude)
```

This values are not pixels but coordinates in the EPSG:900913 projection, and are correct (as long as they are supposed to be in [Idaho](http://maps.google.com/?q=44.615123313472,-113.8085937334033), if not there is something wrong elsewhere)

To check it, you can go to http://proj4js.org/ and transform your coordinates from EPSG:900913 to WGS84 (lat/lon), which will give you:

```
x = -113.8085937334033 (longitude)
y = 44.615123313472 (latitude)
```

This are the values you are probably expecting. If you want to obtain them from the point coordinates use something like:

```
point.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"));
```

This will transform the coordinates from the Google projection to WGS84 (Latitude / Longitude).

Comment: Thanks, I was really having a hard time wrapping my head around the various projections...

Comment: Actually I have a question...I'll ask again formally, but: If I do the opposite (point.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"));
To a regular lat/lon point, I get NaN (not a number?) for any negative lon values... Is this expected?

Comment: This code caused me some bug, the popup was opening not on the marker. Instead this worked perfectly: OpenLayers.Layer.SphericalMercator.inverseMercator(lonlat.lon, lonlat.lat);

Answer (score 2):

As far as I remember, box handler is implementy differently from other handlers in OL. We had to implement an own handler which returns a geometry with lon/lat coordinates rather that with pixel coordinates:

```
Legato.Handler.Box = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Handler.Box, {
  endBox : function(end) {
    var result;
    if (Math.abs(this.dragHandler.start.x - end.x) > 5
        || Math.abs(this.dragHandler.start.y - end.y) > 5) {
      var start = this.dragHandler.start;
      var top = Math.min(start.y, end.y);
      var bottom = Math.max(start.y, end.y);
      var left = Math.min(start.x, end.x);
      var right = Math.max(start.x, end.x);

      var lowerLeftLonLat = this.map.getLonLatFromPixel(new OpenLayers.Pixel(
          left, bottom));
      var upperRightLonLat = this.map.getLonLatFromPixel(new OpenLayers.Pixel(
          right, top));
      var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(lowerLeftLonLat.lon,
          lowerLeftLonLat.lat, upperRightLonLat.lon, upperRightLonLat.lat);
      result = bounds.toGeometry();
    } else {
      var xy = this.dragHandler.start.clone();
      var lonLat = this.map.getLonLatFromPixel(xy);
      result = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lonLat.lon, lonLat.lat);
    }
    this.removeBox();
    this.callback("done", [ result ]);
  },

  CLASS_NAME :"Legato.Handler.Box"
});
```