# How do Bounds work in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

Does the concept of [OpenLayers.Bounds](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/BaseTypes/Bounds-js.html) from OpenLayers 2.x still exist in OpenLayers 3?  How has it changed, and what is its new name?

Comment: var mapExtent = map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize());

Answer (score 8, accepted):

UPDATE: OL4: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.html#.Extent

It seems that the new word for 'bounds' or 'bounding box' (BBOX) is 'extent'.
See:

- http://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/apidoc/ol.extent.html
- http://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/apidoc/ol.View.html#fitExtent
- http://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html#getExtent

One way to find out things at the moment is to run searches in the OL3 repo, for example:
https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/search?p=3&q=BBOX&type=Code

Comment: I can give you some rep for those questions :), that new tag will prove quite useful as OL3 is not compatible with OL3, for the moment both must be used otherwise no one will see those questions.

Comment: I mean 'as OL3 is not compatible with OL2'

Answer (score 7):

Did'nt found any documentation about this feature but **Extent** seems to work :

```
var vectorSources = new ol.source.Vector();
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: map_id,
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: vectorSources
    })
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 12
  })
});

var feature1 = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(coords)
});
vectorSources.addFeature(feature1);
var feature2 = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(coords)
});
vectorSources.addFeature(feature2);
map.getView().fitExtent(vectorSources.getExtent(), map.getSize());
```

The method `vectorSources.getExtent()` can also be replaced by any **Extent** object, like this :

<strike>map.getView().fitExtent([1,43,8,45], map.getSize());</strike>

Since OpenLayer 3.9, the method has changed :

`map.getView().fit(vectorSources.getExtent(), map.getSize());`

Comment: Thanks.  This seems to be the **extent** of the documentation right now: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.extent.html

Answer (score 5):

Just to add a little example to the answer:
Bounds is now called "extent" and it's not a sophisticated Object/Class anymore, but merely an array of four numbers. There're a bunch of helper functions for transformation and so on in "ol.extent". Just a little example on how to to a transformation:

```
var tfn = ol.proj.getTransform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
var textent = ol.extent.applyTransform([6, 43, 16, 50], tfn);
```

```
var textent = ol.proj.transformExtent([6, 43, 16, 50], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
```

<strike>I could not find an API-Doc so far in http://ol3js.org/en/master/apidoc so you have to read the [source](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/master/src/ol/extent.js) to get information.</strike>

<strike>The API-Docs have been completed since the BETA. So you'll find it now.</strike>

As mentioned in the comments, the correct API-function is [ol.proj.transformExtent()](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.proj.html#.transformExtent) now.

Comment: I think ol.extent.transform has been renamed to ol.extent.applyTransform

Comment: The function to use for transforming an extent is `ol.proj.transformExtent`.

Comment: Thank you. At the time of writing this function did not exist. :-)

Answer (score 2):

On OpenLayers 3.17.1 and after trying various thing I was able to set the bounds in two different ways:

A) As [@Grmpfhmbl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2782393/grmpfhmbl) [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22805580/1658526), using `ol.proj.transformExtent` function like below:

```
var extent = ol.proj.transformExtent(
    [-0.6860987, 50.9395474, -0.2833177, 50.7948214],
    "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857"
);

map.getView().fit( extent, map.getSize() );
```

B) A little bit unusual, using `ol.geom.Polygon` like this:

```
// EPSG:3857 is optional as it is the default value
var a = ol.proj.fromLonLat( [-0.6860987, 50.9395474], "EPSG:3857" ),
    b = ol.proj.fromLonLat( [-0.2833177, 50.7948214], "EPSG:3857" ),
    extent = new ol.geom.Polygon([[a, b]]);

map.getView().fit( extent, map.getSize() );
```